# JIRA Issue Collector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jira-plugin

I am having issues resizing the modal for JIRA Issue Collector that my work uses.

```
window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = $.extend(window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS, {
    // ==== set dialog's height to 600px ====
    height : 600
});
```

This is supposed to work according to JIRA Atlassian docs.
Does anybody else know a way around this. The modal is showing up at only 251px in height.

I want to set it to at least 600px in height.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
div#atlwdg-container{
    height:600px!important;
}

iframe#atlwdg-frame{
    height:600px!important;
}
```

in your local CSS

Comment: NB. 99% of the time, adding _!important_ is not the answer.

Comment: Hi Davee,

This is a temporary solution until I find something that allows me to inject into an offsite iframe. Until then it would appear that the only way to resize this modal is to use custom CSS on our end.

Comment: This might be one of the 1%'ers it fits in to then :). Good luck in your search for injecting script into the IFrame - I've not come seen anything yet, I'm afraid!

Comment: I doubt I will, it's a browser security feature I think... unfortunate but that's what you get when you want to bring somebody else's product into yours.